# What is the graphic intuition behind Marginal rate of subsitution

Tags: microeconomics

[image]

So I think I understand the math, but I don't understand the intuition on a 3d graph. Why does the ratio of partial derivatives give us a tangent line on a level curve(indifference curve)? My understanding is  $\frac{\partial U(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1}$ Will give a tangent line parallel to the $U(x_1,x_2), x_1$ plane and $\frac{\partial U(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2}$ Will give a tangent line parallel to the $U(x_1,x_2), x_2$ plane. So why does dividing them end up with a tangent line parallel to the $(x_1, x_2)$ plane?

Comment: Try looking up "implicit differentiation". This video might also help (I love this channel.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb40J4N1fa4

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical concepts we have to recall in order to answer your question  are that of **level curves of a function** and the so-called **theorem of** **implicit functions**, a very important theorem of mathematical analysis. To explain them in short  words isn't an easy task, I hope I can succeed in explaining it a little.

I  give below a short synthesis of these mathematical concept, to make clearer what I will say.

**Level curves of a function**

Through level curves  we  pass from a representation in three dimensions of a function to a representation in two dimensions: we will see that this  is the case of the usual representation of the indifference curves in the plane.

Consider a function $f$ of two real variables, $x_1,x_2$  which assumes values in $R$:

$y=f(x_1,x_2)$

We want to know the pairs $x_1,x_2$ that make the $f$ assume a specific value, say $c$, in $R$. Formally we can write:

$f(x_1,x_2)=c$

This last equation  describes all the pairs $(x_1,x_2)$
that make the function $f$ equal to the constant $c$. The **set of these pairs** is the level curve of the function $f$ corresponding to the constant $c$.

Varying $c$ you have the whole map of level curves of the function $f$.

From a geometrical  point of view, it is as if we 'cut' the 3-dimensional graphic of the $f$
function with a plane parallel to $x_1,x_2$ plane, and project this 'cut' on the $x_1,x_2$ plane. More precisely, geometrically, a level curve is the orthogonal projection on the $x_1,x_2$ of the curves obtained  intersecting the plane $z=c$ and the graphic of the function $z=f(x_1, x_2)$.

This way we pass from the 3-dimensional graphic of $f$to the 2-dimensional graphic of the level curves.

For example, in the  pictures  below there are the 3-dimensional graphic of the function $z=1-x^2-y^2$
and the 2-dimensional graphic of its level curves.

[image]
[image]

In the case of a utility function $U$ it is exactly the same, you 'cut' with planes, corresponding to various constant levels of utility, the utility function and project the level curves of $U$ on the $x_1, x_2$ plane.

This way you obtain, in two dimensions, the usual indifference curves. From a mathematical point they are exactly the level curves of the utility function, as you already said.

**Implicit function theorem**

Let's come back to the pairs of $_1,_2$
that make  $f$ assume a specific value  $c$ in $R$, that is to the equation

$f(x_1,x_2)=c$      or

$f(x_1, x_2)- c=0$.

The problem is if it is possible to have an explicit form of the function, that is if this equation can be explicitly solved for $x_1$ (or $x_2$).

The answer is yes,  **under certain assumptions**.  Under certain assumptions, the equation  can be solved  for  $x_1$ (or $x_2$) , and in this case it defines a function $g$ from $R$ to $R$, that is a function

$x_1=g(x_2)$

that gives explicitly all the pairs  $(x_1,x_2)$ that make the function $f$ equal to the constant $c$.

In this case the equation $f(x_1, x_2)- c=0$ is said the *implicit form* of the function.

The **implicit function theorem states the assumptions** under which such a  function $g$ can be defined.

For an example of case in which such a $g$ function cannot be defined, let's come back to level curves. The point is that **not any level curve represents a function**, for examples the level curves of the picture  above are circumferences, and they do not represent a function, because the equation of a circumference  is not a function (it doesn't satisfy the definition of function).

(The implicit function theorem, however, states conditions under which such a  function can be *locally* defined).

**As for the derivative of $g$** (for example the slope of the indifferences curve),  we resort again to the implicit function theorem.

The implicit function theorem not only states the conditions for the existence of $g$, but **gives us a formula to find its derivative.** It gives the derivative of $g$, $dx_1/dx_2$, in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$:

$(dx_1/dx_2)=-(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2})/(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})$

If you replace  $f$ with $U$, you have the derivative of the indifference curve you wrote in your post.

Then you ask why this way we have a **tangent** in a plane parallel to $_1,_2$ .

Actually, you have not a 'tangent', you have a derivative of a function from $R$ to $R$.

But you know that a derivative  of a function in a certain point geometrically represents the slope of the tangent to the function in that point.

So, knowing the derivative, you can graphically represent  the tangent to a level curve in a certain point in the plane $x_1,x_2$, (or, if you prefer, you can 'lift' this tangent in the 3-dimensional space and see it in the plane that cuts the $f$ function where $f=c$, parallel to the $(_1,_2)$ plane).

By the way, the formulas you wrote to find that derivative are a shortcut, a practical trick to find it,  but the rigorous foundation is the implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer to your question, but I tend to show all my students pages 1-4 of Dixit's Optimization book. It describes exactly what the MRS is doing and why it must be tangent to the budget constraint.

https://www.scribd.com/document/390573490/Dixit-Optimization-in-Economic-Theory-pdf (pages 1-3 here unless you sign in)